# SparkJava using Kotlin and WebSockets

Tags: websocket, kotlin, spark-java

I am trying out Kotlin with SparkJava, and having trouble implementing the WebSockets routes. I am trying to follow the WebSockets example available on the SparkJava website (http://sparkjava.com/tutorials/websocket-chat), and whilst I can get the OnWebSocketConnect and OnWebSocketMessage elements to work, the OnWebSocketClose is not picked up.

I have implemented this in Java to double check that it is not a browser issues, and the Java implementation works fine...so this appears to be something specific to the way Kotlin is interpreting the OnWebSocketClose annotation.

My code looks like the following

```
import spark.Spark.*
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.Session
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.api.annotations.*;

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    staticFileLocation("/public")
    webSocket("/chat", WSHandler::class.java)
    init()
}

@WebSocket
class WSHandler {

    @OnWebSocketConnect
    fun connected(session: Session) = println("session connected")

    @OnWebSocketClose
    fun closed(session: Session, statusCode: Int, reason: String) = println("closed sessions")

    @OnWebSocketMessage
    fun message(session: Session, message: String) = println("Got: $message")
}
```

The html / javascript etc are as per the tutorial on the SparkJava website.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an error during invocation of `closed` method deep inside `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.common.events.annotated.CallableMethod` class with the following message:

> Parameter specified as non-null is null: method
>   webchat.WSHandler.closed, parameter reason

It is related to Kotlin's nullability features and all works fine when you declare your method using signature below:

```
fun closed(session: Session, statusCode: Int, reason: String?)
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. Excellent answer BTW, not only the fix, but the reason for the error.